# Why doesn't specificity formula work for ten enclosed tags?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, w3c

According to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity), second rule has more specificity and text must be blue, but it's red.

```css
/** specificity =  10 */
.my{
     background-color: red;
}

/** specificity =  12 */
html body div b i strong em span font strike ul li{
      background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
<b><i><strong><em><span><font><strike><ul><li class="my">SUPER</li></ul></strike></font></span></em></strong></i></b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because `0,0,1,0 ` is NOT 10.

Comment: Specificity is more of a matrix and **not** a point system you can add up. Early on in web dev I made this same mistake. Selectors fit into four categories with higher weight give to those moving from the right to left. The total of one does not outweigh the total to the left unless that number is `0`, i.e. `0, 1, 0, 0` > `0, 0, 150, 0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See these rules from CSS Tricks:

> For each class value (or pseudo-class or attribute selector), apply 0,0,1,0 points
>
> For each element reference, apply 0,0,0,1 point

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

---

Therefore your first example has 0,0,1,0 points. Whereas your second has 0,0,0,12 points.

**0,0,1,0 > 0,0,0,12**

Basically it doesn't matter how many elements you have referenced in your selector, if you don't have an ID or class referenced then your class selector will always *win*.

[image]

[*CSS Tricks*](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 1):

Second rule has more specificity **only** if the rule has the same hierarchy selector. If you have a class (which is more specific) it will take over.

You can use `li.my`:

```css
/** specificity =  10 */
.my{
     background-color: red;
}

/** specificity =  12 */
html body div b i strong em span font strike ul li.my {
      background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
<b><i><strong><em><span><font><strike><ul><li class="my">SUPER</li></ul></strike></font></span></em></strong></i></b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```